# Returning the matching characters with the result with IndexOf

Tags: c#, string, text-files, indexof

I have a large text file and looking to find some data

Start1234     …data…End

I need to match on Start that has 4 chars in front of it (1234 is just an example) and four spaces in front of that then read to End. This would be fine using IndexOf returning data but I need to return the 1234 with the result, but it is part of the match so won’t be included. Any ideas on how I can to do this?

Comment: "match on Start that has 4 chars in front" the 1234 comees behind Start, so it's not in front. Can you provide a better/another sample and an expected result plesase?

Comment: A bit of code might help as example so we then know what you use in IndexOf. From the text it could be "start","1234","start1234". But from the problem you describe none of the three is it.

Comment: Not started code for it yet just researching best way to di it. I need to find "startcharcharcharcharspacespacespacespace" but return charcharcharspacespacespacespace with the result. Working with an awaful old text file!

Comment: So do you want a method that returns `"1234"`, `"Start1234"`, or something else?

Comment: just "1234" or whatever 4 characters are there (with the data)

Comment: Is there a way to do a wildcard with IndexOf something like "Start****    " So it matches if there are 4 characters there?

Comment: Use RegEx for this one and group the required matches. Try a pattern like `Start(.{4})\s{4}(.*)End` to have the four chars after `Start` in group `1` and what after the 4 spaces to `End` in group `2`. See https://regex101.com/r/o0wUn7/1

Comment: Cheers. Is there a way to check there are 4 spaces after the 4 chars?

Comment: It won't capture if no 4 spaces after the 4 chars/digits/mix... See the first line in the example. Doesn't match.

Comment: Thats great, how would you if matched delete the string?

Comment: Use `RegEx.Replace` to replace the grouped/the whole string with `string.Empty`. This pattern is better: `Start(.{4})\s{4}(.*?)End`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253014/discussion-between-danny-and-dr-null).

Answer (score 2):

> I need to return the 1234 with the result, but it is part of the match
> so won’t be included

That's wrong. If you use `text.IndexOf("1234")` you will get the index before `1234`, so it's included:

```
string text  = "Start1234 …data…End";
string find = "1234";
int index = text.IndexOf(find);
string result = index == - 1
    ? null
    : text.Substring(index); // 1234 …data…End
```

Comment: I need to find "Start1234    " The 1234 is just an example I need to check there are 4 characters and 4 spaces there, then return the value of the 4 character with the data

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong: you need to find the first instance of the word "Start" which is followed by four non-whitespace characters, then four spaces. You then need to extract those four characters and then everything after the four spaces.

If I am correct in my understanding, then this function should do what you want:

```
public bool ParseData(string input, out string trailingFour, out string data)
{
    //Regex explanation
    //(Start): matches the word Start
    //(\S{4}): matches any four characters that are not whitespace
    //( {4}): matches four spaces
    //([\s\S]*): matches all remaining chacters in the string, including newlines
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"(Start)(\S{4})( {4})([\s\S]*)");
    
    //A successful match will have 5 capture groups
    var match = rx.Match(input);
    trailingFour = match.Success ? match.Groups[2].Value : string.Empty;
    data = match.Success ? match.Groups[4].Value : string.Empty;
    
    return match.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [RegEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-8.0) instead of the string methods for this problem. Form a pattern to capture lines:

- Start with literally `Start` word.
- Followed by any four characters `(.{4})`. Grouped to get the value.
- Followed by four whitespaces `\s{4}`.
- Followed by some text `(.*?)`. Grouped to get the value, and
- End with literally `End` word.

Put it together:

```
Start(.{4})\s{4}(.*?)End
```

Example

```cs
var input = "Start1234 …data…End Start3453    sdfsdfsdfsEnd\nStartSLDE    some data.End";
var pattern = @"Start(.{4})\s{4}(.*?)End";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
    Console.WriteLine($"{m.Value}, 1st Group: {m.Groups[1].Value}, 2nd Group: {m.Groups[2].Value}");
```

This will return two matches only:

```
Start3453    sdfsdfsdfsEnd, 1st Group: 3453, 2nd Group: sdfsdfsdfs
StartSLDE    some data.End, 1st Group: SLDE, 2nd Group: some data.
```

Call `RegEx.Replace` method If you need to replace the matches with something else and return a **new** string:

```cs
var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty);
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/M6N9GL/1)